# Why is this question not closed as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons, opinion-based

In the newsletter mailshot today, top of the "Top new questions" list is this one [Why is “!!” considered bad form in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014080/why-is-considered-bad-form-in-perl)

To me this is an obvious example of "Primarily opinion-based" and it already had a couple of corresponding close votes, but it has far more upvotes.

Here's the current explanation for the "Primarily opinion-based" close reason for reference:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Also, please note that [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33020641/1469259) starts with "*The whole question is somewhat subjective, so I'd like to give an opinion that differs*", and **is getting upvoted**, suggesting that opinions *do* differ on this topic.

So I'm wondering if it's because people who don't know better are upvoting it, or if there's a lot of "I know it's off-topic and will probably get closed, but it's interesting, so I'll upvote anyway".

Or is it not as clear-cut as I think, and actually there's a case for keeping it open?

Comment: I haven't really followed what the current consensus is but that seems like the  kind of subjective question that should stay open. It's miles away from the typical "what is the best x product" question that "Opinion-based" is for

Comment: Imo, it is not opinion based as every answer are pointing out the same problem. It is a debate on a single operator and it's usage. The question itself is legit and answers are well documented without opinion .

Comment: @Pekka웃 maybe I'm interpreting wrong here - but I wouldn't even use "Opinion-based" for recommendation-type questions - that's covered under "Off-topic" where "Primarily Opinion-Based" has a more specific description (edited into question now), which seems to fit this case exactly as far as I can see.

Comment: @Cyrbil just because a lot of people share an opinion doesn't make it not an opinion. If there are a bunch of people who disagree with it, it's probably not *fact*, which to me is what this close reason means. Otherwise, I have to quibble with the validity of the close reason.

Comment: @Cyrbil also the fact you said "it is a debate" rings alarm bells in my head... Not saying I agree with it but I thought the general policy was that SO is not the right place for discussions.

Comment: I suspect if the title were "What is the disadvantage of !! in Perl?" it will be closed soon

Comment: @amuse that's interesting, because it's pretty much exactly the opposite of what Benjamin said in his answer - "Pros and cons of a technique questions are fine" (which I questioned as well :-)

Comment: Every [tag] community at SO tends to have their own sensibilities about what kind of Q+A is on topic.  Sometimes not very obvious to an outsider.  Having personally tried to read Perl scripts, and failing rather badly at it, surely intelligibility of Perl code *must* be an on-topic issue in the [perl] community.  If not for the very survival of the language, Python is beating it up pretty badly :)  Another tag where style is heavily on topic btw, the "pythonic way" often comes up.

Answer (score 0):

You know what, I just realized I've been misreading that close reason.

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific
>   expertise.

I had been reading it as

> Many good questions may generate some degree of opinion, but they are not appropriate here

whereas now I see it's really

> Many **acceptable** questions may generate some degree of opinion but **this isn't one of those questions**"...

So one possible answer to my question seems to be:

That close reason does not apply - you're misinterpreting it. It's ok for some degree of opinion, as long as the opinions are backed by "facts, references *or specific expertise*", which clearly applies here. So the question is fine.

Comment: The mentioned question is one that is *primarily* asking for opinions, not one in which there is simply some small amount of subjectivity.  The reason that the close reason is phrased the way it is is because *every single question* you could possibly ask has *some* degree of opinion about what the best answer is.

Answer (score -3):

The question has not been closed because it does not ask whether or not a particular feature is bad or otherwise ask for opinions. Simple as that.

It asks why a feature is *considered* bad by some. As in - what the *objective problems* with a certain technique are. It does not ask if it's a bad practice or not but rather why some consider it a bad practice.

Pros and cons of a technique questions are fine - questions asking for peoples' opinions are not.

---

That said - it is entirely possible that such a question won't be well received and will get a lot of opinion based answers - in that case it should be closed.

Comment: I don't really think it's "as simple as that". Author of the highly-upvoted top answer says in a comment "It might end up being opinion based and thus OT. After all - code idioms you like/dislike are opinion, and code styles are more policy". Another popular answer starts "The whole question is somewhat subjective, so I'd like to give an opinion that differs".

Comment: Also, *are* open-ended "pros and cons" questions ok? A quick search suggests they usually wind up closed

Comment: @CupawnTae I'd say no, as what is a pro and what is a con is opinionated. And pretty much irrelevant as an open-ended question, even the smallest smudge of context can radically change the game.